# Water Filters Before a Shallow Well Jet Pump?

Tags: plumbing

I have a cottage which has ridiculously rusty, hard water. Previously I asked about [putting filters before or after a water softener](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/88544/should-water-sediment-filters-come-before-or-after-water-softener).

My question here is, Can I put a filter, like an in-line rain-fresh filter, before the jet pump? e.g.

```
feed from well --> water filter --> pump --> softener --> tank
```

Comment: Have the water tested by a reputable water softner company. They will tell you just what you can or should do to your well water. If you have  high iron content water, a water softner may not be able to remove all the iron.

Comment: Note that carbon/pleated/string-wound filters are not very effective at removing hardness or dissolved iron.

Comment: Generally I see them from the well pump to the tank to the filter to the softner. It will  definitely help keep the softener clean internally. I have also seen them from the well pump to the filter to the tank to the softener as well. When I had a well I also feed my outside  in front of the filter and after the tank. The drinking water after the filter in front of the softner. Reason for the drinking water was the sodium in the softened water caused by the brine recharge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea.  It will cause a pressure drop in the suction line, and as the filter plugs the resistance will increase.  You can end up cavitating the pump which will erode away the impeller.

Comment: A decent jet pump + controller should, generally speaking, be able to cope with a clogged suction line without annihilating itself. At residential scale, my gut says the electric motor would die long before generating enough cavitation to damage the impeller. Also a filter should reduce deposit buildup on the impeller = reduced turbulence = reduced cavitation.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a FILTER on the suction, but no reason not to use a screen - say 60 mesh to keep the large stuff out of the pump. We have one and it never plugs up, but does collect debris.

Comment: Awesome, I'll likely give that a try when I open up next spring.   Where and how do you install that?